# php imap mark messages as read not working

Tags: php, imap, postfix-mta

I have this version installed PHP fpm Version 5.6.40-38 + ubuntu16.04.1 + deb.sury.org + 1

I am connecting to another Ubuntu / Postfix server 18.04 mailinabox imap protocol. I read the emails without problems but I need to mark them as read and it does not work for me

```php
imap_setflag_full($mbox, 1, "\\Seen", ST_UID);
```

or

```php
imap_setflag_full($mbox, 1, "\\Seen");
```

or

```php
or imap_clearflag_full($mbox, 1, "\\Seen");
```

When I execute any previous instruction it returns `true` but there are no changes, I have tried everything I have found on the internet and I cannot uncheck it, Unseen = U always comes.

How can I see the flags of the postfix server?

Comment: use \\Seen still does not work